# Eventon WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with eventon plugin and at one place I need to show the featured or upcoming event, I couldn't find a short-code for that so, I used a custom query to retrieve all the information, so far so good, it's working.

THE CATCH is, I need to get start date of an event but I'm getting the published date. I can't find it in the wp_postmeta table either, I've triple checked.

Here's the Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts AS post
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id
WHERE post.post_type =  'ajde_events'
AND meta.meta_key =  '_featured'
AND meta.meta_value =  'yes'
AND post.post_status =  'publish'
```

[image]

9th feb is the publish date, where as I need the event date, which is 24th-feb. Again, I've checked multiple times, and I can't find the start date meta-field or column in the database.

Comment: So you are getting event on data with custom query?

Comment: No, I'm getting the published date with custom query, however, I am getting the correct dates using shorcode for list

Comment: Then You can go and check the event on shortcode code that how they are getting the correct date ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your featured post id and then in database go to `wp_postmeta` table and then in meta_key column find the `evcal_srow and evcal_erow`. But it's in unix form so you have to convert it in time format first.

So, in your theme get the post meta values like

```
$start = get_post_meta($id, 'evcal_srow', true);
$end = get_post_meta($id, 'evcal_erow', true);
```

Then use this code to get start date and end date.

```
$start_time = date($format . 'd m, y', $start);
$end_time = date($format . 'd m, y', $end);
```

That's it. :)

Comment: Yes that's the way, it's working but, I can't still get the proper day and time. I think, it's the unix date format conversion that's messed up. I'll look into it.